# Нажатие на кнопку на html-странице с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть HTML страница, на странице есть кнопка, с помощью инструмента разработчика Хром смотрю код этой кнопки:

```
<button type="button" id="compactPitch" class="sc-fzoYHE sc-fznLPX dDZlPu">H6<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sc-AxirZ edGcOh sc-fzoaKM jrzUKX"><path d="M7 10L12 15L17 10H7Z"></path></svg></button>
```

Я выполняю такой JS-код в браузере:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sc-fzoYHE sc-fznLPX dDZlPu")[0].click()
```

И все работает - кнопка действительно нажимается.

Но после того, как кнопка нажимается - выпадает как бы список:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У этих появившихся кнопок, код такой:

```
<ul class="sc-fzoYkl hfPoTr padded">

<li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo"
     
    value="M1">M1</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" 
    
    value="M2">M2</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" 
    
    value="H4">H4</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo selected" 
    
    value="H6">H6</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" 
    //....
    value="H8">H8</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" 
    
    value="D">D</li><li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" value="W">W</li><li
    
     class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" value="MN">MN</li><li class="sc-fznzOf 
    
    iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" value="QR">QR</li></ul>
```

Я пытаюсь нажать на какую либо эти кнопок так же:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo")[0].click()
```

Однако - это уже не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так ?

Comment: А что должно произойти? Сперва вы кликнули по кнопке - появился список. Теперь вы кликаете по тегу li. Была бы ссылка вы на неё перешли бы

Comment: @Александр, когда я кликая этим появившимся "кнопочкам" - то график перестраивается.

Comment: Возможно там более сложная реализация. Для себя можете проверить, работает ли клик. В первый элемент списка, у которого значение М1, который вы находите так document.getElementsByClassName("sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo")[0] подставить onclick="console.log(this)"

Comment: Получится так,
<li class="sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo" value="M1" onclick="console.log(this)">M1</li> 

document.getElementsByClassName("sc-fznzOf iRagVY sc-fznMnq bewonI sc-fzoVTD cqfolo")[0].click()

Comment: @Александр, оказалось надо было сначала "нажать" первую кнопку, то есть сделать сначала первый вызов click(), а потом уже только после первого второй click() уже второго класса.

Comment: ну вот и отлично, рад что разобрались